# I wish to remove, disable or hide the comment authors' links to their sites from my home page

Tags: comments, links

I wish to remove the author's links to their original website, from my page

I know this is in either the functions.php or comments.php files.

I'm not sure exactly of how to edit these php files,

I've come across some code online that basically states that I must insert the following. But I am not sure where exactly to insert the curly brackets or normal brackets etc, so that the lines of code are implemented, and which brackets to use in this case.

Help please. I am new to Wordpress like less than 1 week old. So editing .php files is a bit daunting- but I am looking to learn how to do it successfully.

The website is www.nouvida.com--- I want the comment author's links not to be connected to the Original Theme's homepage..

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'remove_html_link_tag_from_comment_author_link' );

function remove_html_link_tag_from_comment_author_link ( $link ) {

    if( !in_the_loop() ) {
        $link = preg_replace('/<a href=[\",\'](.*?)[\",\']>(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $link);
    }

    return $link;

}
```

Comment: Could you enlighten us a little more with what/where you meant to disable those links. Did you mean on all `comments` on the whole website where the `author` can comment or as Mark mentioned, or only on your `home/front page`. (* the code in my answer now is for the whole site*)

Comment: Currently when one clicks on the Comment Author's name e.g " Marco Perloc"- the link leads to the https://www.proteusthemes.com/ website. I want this link to be broken for the entire website.

Comment: See my answer, it takes care of this.

Comment: To stimulate other maybe even more detailed input from the community (*so others also know if an answer(s) works*), it would be nice to mark an answer as solved / or give a comment at least that it did not (*yet*) help/worked as wished. Please see [how](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code snippet in `functions.php`. (*in your `theme`folder*)

**Edit new code:**
- *This should do the trick, sorry for the delay.*

```
/**
 * Remove post author link on comments
 * 
 * @return string $author
 */
function wpse218025_remove_comment_author_link( $return, $author, $comment_ID ) {
    return $author;
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'wpse218025_remove_comment_author_link', 10, 3 );
```

> Note: you can add `functions` almost always to your `functions.php` in your `theme` folder. Ofcourse is it also possible to make a plugin but that needs a little more coding.
>   Please take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Resources) for making your own plugin.

Comment: I think that she wants to remove it only from the home page....

Comment: @MarkKaplun , you could be absolutely right but then I probably don't understand what is wanted. (*seeing no comment options on her home page, or I am blonde/blinde ..ugh*) As soon she will respond and when needed I will edit of course the code with `if( is_home` etc.

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for reverting so quickly, I would like to remove the Links  in the "Comment Author's name"- currently their are linked to the homepage of the Theme's developers. But I wanted to remove these links altogether on the website. Secondly when the website is up and running, I would then like the "Comment Author's link to lead to the person's email details or FB account.

Comment: @ZoeyNdhlovu, first things first, the answer (that `function`) takes care for disabling `comment authors link` to their website. About point 2 in your comment, ehm "Your email address will not be published." means?! Last, the wish to link to their Facebook page is another "issue", you probably need to add a `field` to the [`comment form`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) to achieve that. But that is another question.

Comment: @Charles, I used the above code snippet and inserted into the functions.php file, However it completely removed the "Author Name"- I would like to include the " Author name" but just break the link to the Website. Which means, If a User inserts a comment on my website, I still would like to see the Person's name. But then don't want to click their name- And then be sent to another destination out of the site...

Comment: @ZoeyNdhlovu, I have updated the code and this time also tested, it *should* work now.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what do you want to make, paste this in your functions.php

```
function alter_comment_form_fields($fields){
    $fields['url'] = '';  //removes website field

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','alter_comment_form_fields');
```

This will remove the website field from the comments form.

If you don't want to display the link on authors comment, try to modify comments.php if it's present in your theme.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I understand her question well and seeing her code she wants to remove the link an author name holds (*only when filled out*) as soon the author add a comment.